# Is it possible to overload add operator for String type in rust?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I'm learning **operator overloading** for my own types. See example below, I'm implementing the `Add` trait from standard library for my own `Point` type.

```rust
impl Add<Point> for Point {
    type Output = Point;
    fn add(self, point: Point) -> Self::Output {
        Point {
            x: self.x + point.x,
            y: self.y + point.y,
        }
    }
}
```

then I can add 2 instances of `Point` type using the following syntax:

```rust
let point_c = point_a + point_b;
```

How can I implement the same for string literals `&str` or built in types like `String`? 
I tried the below it failed:

```rust
impl Add<String> for String {
    type Output = String;

    fn add(self, string: String) -> Self::Output {
        self.push_str(string);
    }
}
```

I don't have any practical need of doing this with `String`, but want to understand that can I only implement the operator overloading traits on my own types? can't I do the same on built in types?

I'm getting the below error in VS code:

> Only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types

#### Update: Resolution:

```rust
struct MyString(String);


    impl Add<MyString> for MyString{
        type Output= MyString;
        fn add(self,input:MyString)->Self::Output{
            let mut own_str=self.0.to_string();
            let input_str=input.0.to_string();
            own_str.push_str(&input_str);
            MyString(own_str)
        }
    }

    let mystring_first_name=MyString(String::from("Anil"));
    let mystring_last_name=MyString(String::from("Khandei"));

    let my_full_name=mystring_first_name+ MyString(String::from(" ")) +mystring_last_name;
    println!("{:?}",my_full_name.0);
```

Comment: The tl;dr of it is: no, you can't.

Comment: i was finally able to do it using the help of the other post.

Comment: I understand that the point of this question is to learn operator overloading. But for the record, `String` already has [`+` overloaded](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20str%3E).